# Blackberry - handling file of camera application invocation

Tags: blackberry, camera, invoke

Hi Guys
I was wondering what is the best way to handle data that was created in invoked native camera application on blackberry.
Lets say that user invoked photo application by clicking on a button, took a photo, saved it in on sd card.

```
CameraArguments app_camera = new CameraArguments();
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_CAMERA, app_camera);
```

My application has `FileSystemJournalListener` that grabbed the path of stored photo.

And now my application has to handle the file and display new screen once its on foreground again.

What is the best way to terminate the camera application and gain the back the focus ?

thx

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it the right way, add the journal listener when you invoke the camera then remove it once you have your image. You could try and kill the native camera app with key-injection (warning - this is never a good way to write software) and your app should be sat underneath it when it quits.

Instead of bothering with messy key-injection I just use myApp.requestForeground() when the journal listener detects a new image file has been created - leaving the native phone app in the background.

I think in the newer OS api there are better methods for handling this but we still generally support all the way back to 4.2.1 on a common codebase.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, I am working on 4.6 OS and unfortunately there are no better ways, as far as I know. My problem is in catching the event of user returning to my application. Currently I have code in onExposed() in underlying screen, which is called when in simulator on click of back button in camera, but not on real device. Another thing is when running in simulator onExposed() is called and everything works great until the next time I am invoking camera, instead of showing the camera there is a black screen. thx